# Even numbers in Python

Tags: python, range

Does anyone know if Python has an in-built function to work to print out even values. Like range() for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[Range has three parameters.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)

You can write `range(0, 10, 2)`.

Answer (score 12):

Just use a step of 2:

```
range(start, end, step)
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if this is what you want to hear, but it's pretty trivial to filter out odd values with list comprehension.

```
evens = [x for x in range(100) if x%2 == 0]
```

or

```
evens = [x for x in range(100) if x&1 == 0]
```

You could also use the optional step size parameter for `range` to count up by 2.

Comment: You could also write `map(lambda x: x * 2, range(0, 50))`

Comment: Complement that last comprehension to get odds: 
odds = [x for x in range(100) if x&1 !=0]

Comment: If the filtering criteria were more complex this would be fine, but IMHO it's overkill when you can just pass `range` a `step` arg. Why create integer objects just to throw them away when you can avoid creating them in the first place?

Comment: Nice evenness optimization with "if x&1 == 0"

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
range( 0, 10, 2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> if 100 % 2 == 0 : print "even"
...
even
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

b = [i for i in a if i % 2 == 0]

print("Original List -->", a,"\n")
print("and the Even Numbers-->", b)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Note that this is a very old question that already contains many good answers. In particular, [the answer by Sapph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184774/2124834) already contains the technique you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a few ways to write a lazy, infinite iterators of even numbers.

We will use the `itertools` module and [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools)<sup>[1](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.iterate)</sup> to make iterators that emulate `range()`.

```
import itertools as it

import more_itertools as mit


# Infinite iterators
a = it.count(0, 2)
b = mit.tabulate(lambda x: 2 * x, 0)
c = mit.iterate(lambda x: x + 2, 0)
```

All of the latter options can generate an infinite sequence of even numbers, `0, 2, 4, 6, ...`.

You can treat these like any generator by looping over them, or you can select `n` numbers from the sequence via [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) or `take` from the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) e.g.:

```
mit.take(10, a)
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

This is equivalent to `list(range(0, 20, 2))`.  However, unlike `range()`, the iterator is paused and will yield the next batch of even numbers if run again:

```
mit.take(10, a)
# [20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38]
```

---

**Details**

The options presented are all infinite iterators that `start` with an integer, i.e. `0`.

- a. `itertools.count` yields the next value incremented by a `step=2` (see [equivalent code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)).
- b. `more_itertools.tabulate` is an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that maps a function to each value of a number line (see [source code](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/recipes.py#L95-L110)).
- c. [`more_itertools.iterate`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.iterate) yields the starting value (`0`).  It then applies a function to the last item (incrementing by 2), yields that result and repeats this process (see [source code](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/blob/master/more_itertools/more.py#L391-L401)).

<sup>[1](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.iterate)<sub>A third-party package that implements many useful tools, including [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) such as `take` and `tabulate`.</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

```
#This is not suggestible way to code in Python, but it gives a better understanding


numbers = range(1,10)

even = []

for i in numbers:

     if i%2 == 0:

       even.append(i)
print (even)
```