# How is it possible to use a while loop to print even numbers 2 through 100?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am a beginner and I am stuck on this problem, "Write a python code that uses a while loop to print even numbers from 2 through 100. Hint ConsecutiveEven differ by 2."

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
 while num in range(22,101,2):
              print(num)
```

Comment: Whats the problem? What does your current code do that you didn't expect (or not do that you did expect)?

Comment: That's a `for` loop with `while` written instead.

Comment: Here's a hint: `while num <= 100:`

Comment: So a `while` loop keeps going as long as a condition is true. Think about what such a loop would have to do if you started with `i = 2` and `while i <= 100:` was the loop condition..

Comment: You can see this question it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184745/even-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Use either `for` with `range()`, or use `while` and explicitly increment the number. For example:

```
>>> i = 2
>>> while i <=10: # Using while
...    print(i)
...    i += 2
...
2
4
6
8
10

>>> for i in range(2, 11, 2): # Using for
...    print(i)
...
2
4
6
8
10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd try:

```
i=2
while i <= 100:
    if ( i % 2==0):
        print (i, end=', ')
    i+=1
```

Comment: While this code may technically answer the question, adding an explanation will greatly help the OP and future visitors. This is especially true for beginning level questions, where users are trying to understand the concept of how programs, and languages work. Please use the `edit` button to add an explanation to the supplied code. Thank you for helping make SO a great community for coders of all levels.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use the while loop

```
 while [condition]:
     logic here
```

using while in range is incorrect.

```
num = 0
while num <=100:
    if num % 2 == 0:
        print(num)
    num += 1
```

Comment: Why not `num += 2`

Comment: Then you do not need to check `num%2` @Mani

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

- Substituting `while` for a statement with `for` syntax. `while` takes a bool, not an iterable.
- Using incorrect values for `range`: you will start at 22.

With minimal changes, this should work:

```
for num in range(2, 101, 2):
    print(num)
```

Note that I used `101` for the upper limit of `range` because it is *exclusive*. If I put `100` it would stop at `98`.

If you need to use a `while` loop:

```
n = 2
while n <= 100:
    print (n)
    n += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for while write a function  that shall display only even numbers from 1 to 20. Make sure your function is called printer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).