# While Loops - Increment a List

Tags: python

I'm stuck trying to figure out this while loop. It seemed simple at first but I keep running into errors. I think I just haven't used python in a while so it's hard to get back into the gist of things.

> Write a while loop that will add 100 numbers to a list, starting from the number 100 and incrementing by 2 each time. For example, start from 100, then the next number added will be 102, then 104 and so on.

I have this so far;

```
count = 0
while count < 99:
    count += 1
    numbers.append(len(numbers)+2)

for x in numbers:
    print(x)
```

But that is simply giving me 0-100 printed out when I want it to be 2,4,6,8,10,...

Comment: What kind of errors are you running into? What is `numbers`? Why do you want it to start from `2` when the exercise asks you to start from `100`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is it possible to use a while loop to print even numbers 2 through 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094424/how-is-it-possible-to-use-a-while-loop-to-print-even-numbers-2-through-100)

Comment: No, it prints `2`, `3`, `...`, `100`, because you are just adding the current length of the list (shifted by 2) to the end of the list each time through.

Comment: What is your task? Should it be to add 100 number to a **collection** or add 100 numbers to an **accumulator**. That is, do you need to end up with a collection of 100 numbers or a single number which is the sum of a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = []

index = 0
number = 100
while index < 100:
    number += 2
    index += 1
    numbers.append(number)

for x in numbers:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

With a few modifications, and using a while loop as per your exercise:

```
numbers = []
count = 0
while count < 100:
    numbers.append(100 + (2*count))
    count += 1

for x in numbers:
    print(x)
```

Or with a for loop:

```
numbers = []
for i in range(100):
    numbers.append(100 + (2*i))

for x in numbers:
    print(x)
```

Or as a list comprehension:

```
numbers.extend([(100 + (2*el)) for el in range(100)])
```

Or as a recursion:

```
numbers = []
def rec(num):
    if num < 100:
        numbers.append(100 + (2*num))
        rec(num + 1)
rec(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `numbers.extend(range(100, 300, 2))`. It's a much shorter way to do exactly what you're looking for.

Edit: For the people downvoting, can you at least leave a comment? My initial response was prior to the question being clarified (that a while loop was required). I'm giving the pythonic way of doing it, as I was unaware of the requirement.

Comment: This is the "good" way to do this, but it's not the "right" way, given that the user's (presumed homework) assignment is to write a `while` loop.

Comment: This worked great. Can't believe I didn't think of this easy fix. Thank you!!

Comment: No it works for what I needed, as I just replace my append with this line and it does the job within the while loop I already had set up

Comment: Cha04F - don't do that, you'll be extending it 100 times

Comment: The while loop requirement was always in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
numbers = []
while len(numbers) != 100:
    if len(numbers) > 0:
        numbers.append(numbers[-1] + 2)
    else:
        numbers.append(100)
```

Little explanation: 
You loop until your list has 100 elements. If list is empty (which will be at the beginning), add first number (100, in our case). After that, just add last number in list increased by 2.