# Why is the index not being incremented by 2 positions in this for loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iterator, increment

I have a similar code that needs incrementing and while loop cant be used there,

```
m = range(10)
for i in range(len(m)):
    print(i)
    i+=2
```

Comment: `for i in range(0, 10, 2)`? range takes a 3rd parameter, step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Even numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184745/even-numbers-in-python)

Comment: There is a need to increment only for certain conditions and not for every iteration, so that wouldn't work. Thank you for the response.

Comment: `range` emits a new value for `i` each turn through the loop. Whatever you do to `i` in one turn does not affect its value in the next turn.

Comment: Then its not possible without a while loop(or super cludgy for looping that just emulates a while loop)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
m = range(10)
nb = 0
for i in range(len(m)):
    print(nb)
    nb+=2
```

The problem is that you wanted to use `i` for two different tasks.